# Wordpress SEO Page Tempates

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a Wordpress website where I can upload Couriers names  (as page, category or tags) and ECommerce Platform names (as page, category or tags) and it generates many to many relationship pages for "Courier + Platform" combination using the same template.

For example if Couriers are UPS, DHL and USPS and Platforms are Shopify and WooCommerce it generates or when someone hits a url they can discover the below combinations.

UPS + Shopify
UPS + WooCommerce

DHL + Shopify
DHL + WooCommerce

USPS + Shopify
USPS + WooCommerce

Possible in Wordpress?